# Time complexity on multiple variables & functions

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, computation-theory

I have written an algorithm to read in a text file and extract the contents inside into two array, then sort. The program is working but I am confuse at calculating the time complexity. Just needed someone to clarify on this.

Say I have two functions, a main and a helper.

Helper function

```
insertion(int array[], int length)
    ...
```

Main function

```
int main()
    while(...) // this while loop read the input text file and push integer into vector
        ...
        while(...)
            ...

    if(...)
        for(...) // this for loop validates array B only
    
    insertion(arrayA, lengthA)
    insertion(arrayB, lengthB)
```

1. Program read in text file
2. Push line 1 to array A, push line 2 to array B
3. 'for loop' to validate array B array integers with an outer 'if'
4. Perform insertion sort on array A and array B

From what I learnt, I have to let number of data be 'n' before calculating the Big-O or number of operations. Now, obviously there are two data points here - one for array A and one for array B.

So, array A = n and array B = m.

However, I am unsure whether the number of data in the helper function should be using 'n' or 'm'. Likewise for the nested while loop, if the number of data should also be using 'n' or 'm'.

I tried my best to explain my difficulty in understanding this time complexity along with a simplified form of my program (the actual program has tons of loops...). Hopefully someone can understand what I mean and provide some clarification or else I will modify further to see if I can make it clearer. Thanks!

Edit: I am required to calculate the number of operations before finding the Big-O for my algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that after you read the file, will have array A and B.
If m and n is close, then you can say that m = n. Otherwise, you choose the biggest one and say it is n.

Then you read n two time, n + n = 2, but in big O, you can take out the constant, then at this point you have O(n) time.

If validate only pass one time through your array B, then you say 3n of complexity time, but 3 still a constant, then time complexity still O(n).

But, the worse case insertion sort can do is O(n^2). You do it two time n^2 + n^ 2 = 2*n^2, two is a constant, so time of insertion sort peace takes O(n^2).

Finally, you have O(n) + O(n^2). Since it's big notation, the most cost part is the really significant part: O(n^2) is your complexity.

For example, if you use insertion sort n times, then you'd have O(n(n^2)) time, which is O(n^3).

The computer do 10^9 operation per second. So small n doesn't count so much.

If you not sure if n and m is close, let's says that 0 < n < 10^9 and 0 < m < 10^3. You'd say that time complexity of inputs is O(n+m). Then insertion sort O(n^2) + O(m^2). But still here, m << n (m is much less than n), you can equally not consider m (I'm saying m here is almost optional IF YOU'RE not being strict!). IF you need be strict, do not ignore at first this small cases.

If 0 < n < 10^9 and 0 < m < 10^9, then you should't say m = n, or ignore anyone. Because n can be one, and m one million.

Comment: Thanks. Prior to finding the Big-O, I am required to find the number of operations that my algorithm takes (my bad, forget to mention in the question). n has 6 elements while m has 2 elements in this case; not too sure what you mean by m and n is close. This is why I needed to separate the two inputs which also confusions me on what my helper function should be (whether n or m)

Comment: m and n is close if it's n and m is 2 and 6. The difference happens in order of 10^3 or above(up).

Comment: Now  I'm finished. Hahah